# Why does creating a table with a serial column create a sequence with a max val of a bigint?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am a little confused and new to PostgreSql , I thought that serial = integer and bigserial = bigint, so I am confused why I see a sequence with a max val of 9223372036854775807 instead of 2147483647, when I create a table with a PK that is serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the PostgreSQL 9.4 docs for Data Type SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) a sequence is implicitly created using `CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq` without any additional parameters.

The [documentation for `CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createsequence.html) says:

> The optional clause *MAXVALUE* **maxvalue** determines the maximum value for the sequence. If this clause is not supplied or *NO MAXVALUE* is specified, then default values will be used. The defaults are 2^63-1 and -1 for ascending and descending sequences, respectively.

So it is documented behaviour that the sequence is created with the max value you are seing.

Comment: And although the maxvalue is 64 bits the type is still an integer.

Comment: So what would be the preferred way to create a sequential key on a table and be able to specify the max value. I would guess just create a pk on the corresponding type and create the sequence yourself and set the max value.

Comment: Just use that SQL statements that are equivalent to using SERIAL and add `MAXVALUE 2147483647` at the end of the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement. Should the sequence ever reach that maximum value you'll be in trouble anyway. So just leave as is and this will eventually cause an `integer out of range` error if all valid integer numbers are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence and the column are two separate things.  A sequence could return an integer larger than an int4 column could store.  When you specify `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL`, PostgreSQL roughly translates that into:

1. create an int4 or int8 column
2. create a sequence
3. make the sequence owned by the column
4. make the column default value the next value from the sequence

`SERIAL` is a convenience, but there is not an actual column type `SERIAL`.